# Excel VBA Error Handling (simple but i can't figure it out)

Tags: vba, excel

Ok i'm trying to put an Error control where if the activecell row returns an error, it will occupy a cell in the row and just write "Error" on it. The code works fine until i put the On Error Control. I think i need advise on the proper placement of the If else where the "Error" word will be put into. Below is the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim outlookapp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myusername As String
Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, DestRow As Long, DestLast As Long
Dim checkstatus As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet


Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next



For CurRow = 2 To LastRow



myusername = Environ("Username")
Set outlookapp = New Outlook.Application
Set outlookmail = outlookapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\" & myusername & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\testtemplate.oft")


With outlookmail

.SentOnBehalfOfName = "SharedMailbox"


.To = ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 6)
.Subject = Replace(outlookmail.Subject, "xProjID", ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 1))
.Subject = Replace(outlookmail.Subject, "xProjName", ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 2))
.Subject = Replace(outlookmail.Subject, "xVert", ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 5))
.HTMLBody = Replace(outlookmail.HTMLBody, "xXName", ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 2))
.HTMLBody = Replace(outlookmail.HTMLBody, "xProjID", ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 1))
.HTMLBody = Replace(outlookmail.HTMLBody, "xStat", ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 10))
.HTMLBody = Replace(outlookmail.HTMLBody, "xManID", ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 6))
.HTMLBody = Replace(outlookmail.HTMLBody, "xName", ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 7))


End With


ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 11) = "Yes"
ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 12) = DateTime.Now

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 13) = "Error"

End If

outlookmail.Send



Next CurRow

MsgBox "Mass Mailer Complete"


End Sub
```

So what this does is it gets the Outlook Alias of a particular user and send the email to him/her. So i tried to put erroneous Alias like "xxxx". The thing is the word "error" which is supposed to be on activecell.cells(currow,13) for the rows with "xxxx" gets logged with rows with the Correct Alias. so where should i put the code if err code?

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

ActiveCell.Cells(CurRow, 13) = "Error"

End If
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why `ActiveCell.Cells` and not `ws1.Cells`?

Comment: [VBA Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3211/error-handling#t=201706021519538153681) on Docs.SO should have everything you need to know. Replace `On Error Resume Next` with proper error handling. That said, you're not clearing the error state (`Err.Clear`) between iterations - that's probably what your problem is.

Comment: In addition to what @Mat'sMug suggests, if I understand your post correctly, I think you also may want to look into the [Resolve Recipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862796.aspx) method in Outlook VBA. You can send email if contact is resolved and if not you can place the error in the cell. In this way there's no need for any Error Trapping as you have it. As written, the code will not generate any error on the Excel side, which is why you are not getting any error.

Comment: hi. i am indeed getting an exception error message in excel . what i mean by "log the error message" is i want the word "error" on activecell.cells(currow,13). i will be trying your suggestions in a bit.

Comment: hi siddhart. thank you. i haven't thought of that. ws1 does make more sense. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, always try to make your code as simple as you can and eliminate the useless things, just to the things that do not work. 
You need something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    On Error Resume Next

    Debug.Print 5 / 0

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Cells(1, 1) = Err.Description
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Then starting from there, you can build the code further. If you need a loop and `Err.Clear` as supposed in the comment from @Mat's Mug, it will look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim lngCounter      As Long
    Dim lngcounter2     As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    Cells.Clear

    For lngCounter = 1 To 5

        Debug.Print lngCounter / IIf(lngCounter Mod 2 = 0, 1, 0)

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Cells(lngCounter, 1) = Err.Description
        End If

        Err.Clear

    Next lngCounter

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

This gives 3 errors in 5 iterations and writes their description in column A of the active excel worksheet.

Comment: hi. thanks. the err.description property helped although i was not able to fully use your code. i needed to put the if err.number condition below the mail.send method and it's working now. thank you for the help.